# flux or gasfluxes package usage in R

Tags: r

So I am very new to R and I have collected greenhouse gas samples from chambers installed in soils. Now I have obtained the raw data from GC (in ppm) for gas concentration for CO2, CH4 and N2O. I want to calculate the flux using flux or gasfluxes package in R. I am not sure how to do that exactly and how to arrange the data properly for that... I couldn't find any tutorial regarding this package on internet. Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

These are are the variables I have

Treatment,      Time (min),    Gas conc. (ppm),   Volume of chamber,    Area of chamber,     Temperature (C) inside the chamber.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! So, when you're new to a package, the first thing you wanna do is find the vignette. In this case, your package doesn't have a vignette, but it does at least have a [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gasfluxes/gasfluxes.pdf). Here you can find the `gasfluxes` function, which you're probably going to have to do first. Try to find the functionality you want and traceback from that function

Comment: The gasfluxes package assumes some familiarity with GHG flux calculation. After data import, your first step should be converting the molar fractions into mass concentrations based on the Ideal Gas Law. Then use the gasfluxes function as explained in the documentation.

Comment: Also, I can assure you that the maintainers of the flux and gasfluxes packages are nice and helpful guys. Don't hesitate to contact them if you find the documentation insufficient. However, first read some R introductions and papers about flux calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much, the reference manual really helped.

Comment: @Roland, So,I wanted to calculate GHGs using the equations from literature. However, I find it very difficult to apply those equations since I was trying to do it in excel then I got to know about this gasfluxes function in R. Is that the only function in R to calculate GHGs or is it possible to my user defined function by using GHGs flux equation such as flux = Hx dC/dT x mP/RT, where dC/dT is the change in concentration over time, m is molecular weight of trace gas, P is atmospheric pressure, R is a gas constant and T is the air temperature inside the chamber, H is the height of the chamber.

Comment: You want the gradient at time zero. For that you need to fit a concentration-time model. There are several models available. I advise to use the HMR model or the linear model based on a reproducible decision criterion. The gasfluxes package facilitates efficient model fitting and gradient/flux calculation. It's been used to calculate thousands of fluxes in a few minutes. You can't do that in Excel. However, the package does not include application of the Ideal Gas Law because users should understand what they are doing and not apply a package function blindly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I typically do:

```
setwd("E:/.../.../")
library(gasfluxes)

DT <- fread("input.csv")

#calculate mass concentrations, example for N2O in ppb --> µg N / m³
# M = 28 g/mol
#Vm = 22.4 L/mol
DT[, N2O := Cmol * 28 * 273.15 / 22.4 / (273.15 + temp)]
```

Chamber volume should be in m³, area in m², closing times in h. Usually I have also columns for treatment, plot and date.

```
#flux calculation --> µg N / m² / h
fluxes <- gasfluxes(DT, 
                 methods = c("linear", "robust linear", "HMR"), 
                 .id = c("treatment", "plot", "date"),
                 .V = "V", .A = "A", .times = "time", .C = "N2O")

#select fluxes
fluxes[, c("flux", "flux.se", "flux.p", "method") := list(robust.linear.f0,
                                                       robust.linear.f0.se,
                                                       robust.linear.f0.p,
                                                       "robust linear")]
fluxes[!is.finite(flux), c("flux", "flux.se", "flux.p", "method") := list(linear.f0,
                                                                       linear.f0.se,
                                                                       linear.f0.p,
                                                                       "linear")]

fluxes[is.finite(HMR.f0) & HMR.AIC < linear.AIC & HMR.kappa < 20, 
        c("flux", "flux.se", "flux.p", "method") := list(HMR.f0,
                                                         HMR.f0.se,
                                                         HMR.f0.p,
                                                         "HMR")]
fluxes[!is.finite(flux), method := "error"]
```

Note that the decision `HMR.kappa < 20` depends on units, is a bit arbitrary and requires more research and would possibly need to be adjusted for number of concentration-time points per flux and soil properties.

**Edit 2020-08-04:**

This is not up-to-date anymore. Please refer to the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gasfluxes/vignettes/gasfluxes-howto.html) which shows the approach from Hüppi et al. (2018).

Comment: Thanks Roland. I have one more question if someone can help me please. So if I use this equation: flux=dCdT*((m*P*volume)/(area*R (gas constant)*Temperature in the chamber)). Where P is 101.3kPa, R is 8.314 J mol-1 K-1, and Time is in hours, m is molecular mass such as 44.01 for CO2, Volume is in m3 and C (concentration) is in ppm, and Temperature is in C. What would be the output result's unit?  would it be mg CO2 per m2 per hour?